zsh glob to find directories that are empty or that only contain a .DS_Store
Is there any zsh glob that will find directories that are either empty or that only contain a .DS_Store file?
I know that the (/^F) glob flag combo will find empty directories, but I also want to include directories that contain only a .DS_Store file but that contain no other nodes (files, directories, etc.).
For my purposes, if I cannot filter out specifically .DS_Store, filtering out either all hidden files (.*(.)) or all hidden nodes (.*) will suffice.

Since they're mutually exclusive searches try find /directory -empty -type d then find /directory -name ".DS_Store"

I'm trying to use a glob to keep it zsh native for portability & performance, and so I can learn how to use more advanced features of zsh. FYI: find has an -or operator, so the two find calls can be combined.

Performance-wise and portability I'd say use find. Using -o (POSIX compliant) can get complicated quite fast imo, but that's subjective.

This looks like something for https://apple.stackexchange.com/ in particular, https://unix.stackexchange.com/ in general, or https://superuser.com/ as a last resort.

The meat of this question is not specific to macOS. The same solution would work on zsh on any platform. There are 6.1k+ zsh questions on Stack Overflow, 3k+ on unix, 1.4k+ on superuser, and 400+ on Ask Different, so I went with Stack Overflow.

For all "hidden files" in a directory tree below directory top, top/**/.*(ND) should do.

@user1934428 I want to filter out .DS_Store or all hidden files

You get all non-hidden files by top/**(N). However this leaves open the problem of hidden directories. How do you want to treat a file i.e. top/.hidden/not_hidden.txt? You haven't specified this in your question.

@user1934428 In my use case, I won't have any hidden directories. But answers that handle hidden directories would be useful for more general use cases.  I don't want files like top/.hidden/not_hidden.txt to be output, as I only want directories. I don't want a directory that contains any node other than .DS_Store, or, alternatively, either files or nodes that are not hidden. I've updated my question to clarify.

Not simple, but we could do:
setopt extendedglob  # for '~' and '#q' in the `[[ … ]]' form
setopt globstarshort # shortcut for '**/*' to '**'

print -rC1 -- **(DN/^F,/e['[[ -z $REPLY/*~*/.DS_Store(#qoNDNY1) ]]'])

lists empty directories or directories in which any file does not exist
other than .DS_Store (in other words: only .DS_Store exits).

**(…):
GLOB_STAR_SHORT
shortcut for **/*.

*(…): Glob
qualifiers
specify which filenames that otherwise match the given pattern will
be inserted in the argument list.

D: set
GLOB_DOTS,
include dotfiles,dirs.

N: set
NULL_GLOB,
don't signal error if pattern does not match. (Not required for
particularly testing/experimenting.)

/^F: zsh idiom for empty directories.

,: OR

/e[…]: directories AND estring qualifier that is directories
which satisfy the zsh code string that is ….

[[ -z … ]]: will describe no file exists other than .DS_Store
using glob patterns.

$REPLY: during execution e[…] , the filename currently being
tested in this case directoryname will be passed by zsh.

*~*/.DS_Store: X~Y means match anything that matches the pattern
X but does not match Y. So, it will expand anything other than
.DS_Store.

#q: globbing performed in the [[ -z … ]] form.

oN: no sort.

D:
GLOB_DOTS
again.

N: set
NULL_GLOB,
let zsh not signal error while processing e[…].

Y1: short-circuit, only the first 1 match will be considered is
enough.


setopt extendedglob globstarshort
rm -rf tester
mkdir tester
cd tester
mkdir empty dsstore-only more-dotfiles more
touch dsstore-only/.DS_Store more-dotfiles/{.DS_Store,.DS_Store.old} more/{.DS_Store,more}
mkdir child
cp -a ^child child
tree -a
#>> .
#>> ├── child
#>> │   ├── dsstore-only
#>> │   │   └── .DS_Store
#>> │   ├── empty
#>> │   ├── more
#>> │   │   ├── .DS_Store
#>> │   │   └── more
#>> │   └── more-dotfiles
#>> │       ├── .DS_Store
#>> │       └── .DS_Store.old
#>> ├── dsstore-only
#>> │   └── .DS_Store
#>> ├── empty
#>> ├── more
#>> │   ├── .DS_Store
#>> │   └── more
#>> └── more-dotfiles
#>>     ├── .DS_Store
#>>     └── .DS_Store.old
#>>
#>>10 directories, 10 files

print -rC1 -- **(DN/^F,/e['[[ -z $REPLY/*~*/.DS_Store(#qoNDNY1) ]]'])
#>> child/dsstore-only
#>> child/empty
#>> dsstore-only
#>> empty

Note: some references:

Glob Qualifires:
...
More than one of these lists can be combined, separated by commas. The
whole list matches if at least one of the sublists matches (they are
`or'ed, the qualifiers in the sublists are `and'ed). Some
qualifiers,
---  Glob Qualifires,
zshexpn(1)


Conditional Expressions:
...
Filename generation is not performed on any form of argument to
conditions. However, it can be forced in any case where normal shell
expansion is valid and when the option EXTENDED_GLOB is in effect by
using an explicit glob qualifier of the form (#q) at the end of the
string.
---  Conditional Expressions,
zshmisc(1)


Ahh - tried to make [[ -z <glob> ]] work, looks like I needed both extendedglob and the (#q...)  qualifier format. Learned something - thanks!

Note that Y implies oN. It could be simplified to [[ -z $REPLY/^.DS_Store(#qDNY1) ]]. Or use ()((!$#)) $REPLY/^.DS_Store(DNY1) using an anonymous function that checks if it got any argument.

This should produce a list of directories that only have a .DS_Store file:
checkDir() {
    setopt extendedglob localoptions
    REPLY=${${REPLY:h}:-.}
    local -a files=($REPLY/^.DS_Store(NDY1))    
    return ${#files}
}
print -lr -- **/.DS_Store(.+checkDir)

It uses the + glob qualifier to filter the matching results. Some of the pieces:

**/.DS_Store(.+checkDir) - the initial glob statement:

**/ - search through the current directory and its subdirectories.
.DS_Store - files named .DS_STORE.
(.) - include only regular files.
(+checkDir) - test each result with the checkDir function.


checkDir() ... - zsh function:

setopt extendedglob localoptions - enable extended glob operators. With localoptions, the setting will only apply to this function.
REPLY=${${REPLY:h}:-.} - REPLY is both the input and the output for the function.

${REPLY:h} - the input is a path of a .DS_Store file; this will give us the base directory (head).
${...:-.} - if the directory is empty, the file is in the current directory - set the displayed result to ..


local -a files=($REPLY/^.DS_Store(NDY1)) - build a list of files in the directory in REPLY.

$REPLY/^.DS_Store - with ^, the list will be files not named .DS_Store.
(N) - no error if list is empty (Null).
(D) - include filenames starting with ..
(Y1) - short circuit. Only testing for the presence of files; this will stop building the list if anything is found.


return ${#files} - set the return code for the function.

$#files == 0 - include the directory name stored in REPLY in the results.
$#files != 0 - omit this entry from the results.






Empty directories can be added by combining the above glob expression with another expression that uses the (/^F) qualifier:
=> print -lr -- **/ **/*(.D) | sort
aa/
bb/
bb/.DS_Store
cc/
cc/.DS_Store
cc/anotherfile
=> print -lr -- **/.DS_Store(N.+checkDir) **/*(N/^F)
bb
aa
=> cd bb
=> print -lr -- **/.DS_Store(N.+checkDir)
.


Edited to add - this can be quite a bit shorter if the spec is empty directories and directories where all the files start with .:
print -lr -- **/(e{'fl=($REPLY/*(NY1));((!$#fl))'})


The $REPLY/^.DS_Store notation quite reliable!
